# Status code from XMLHttpRequest is returning as 0. Tried everything to rectify but hasnt worked till now

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run the following JS code locally on my computer as well as on codepen and in both places its returning me a status of 0, even though the link generated is perfectly fine. What can be the issue here? Have tried searching the net for cross-domain issues and have tried to set a NODE server/set headers explicitly to allow cross domain request, but nothing has worked till now.

```
window.onload = function(){
    let search = document.querySelector('input');
    const API_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json";

    search.addEventListener('change', function(){
        let term = this.value;
        let url = `${API_URL}&search=${term}`;
        console.log(url);
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(xhr.status === 200){
                console.log("ok");
            }
        };

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send(null);

        console.log(xhr.status);

    });
};
```

Comment: `console.log(xhr.status)` is executed when the request is not yet sent ([state `UNSENT (numeric value 0)`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#states)).

Comment: Ajax is a async operation. the initial value is zero. [Off the top of my head] you'll want a `onreadystatechange` event listener not `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

The `xhr.status` is available inside the `onload method`, status is only set after the `onload` method has been called.

```
xhr.onload = function(){
console.log(xhr.status);
    if(xhr.status === 200){
        console.log("ok");
    }
};
```